# Initiate Pace.js only on page initial load

Tags: javascript, html, css, preload

I'm trying to use Pace.js (http://github.hubspot.com/pace/) as an initial page preloader for a site, but I'm not sure how to make it run just once. By default it runs every time there's a page refresh, and the only settings I've seen is if it's supposed to also run on ajax / pushstate requests. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

On the rest of the pages where you dont want to include pace loader you have to use `Pace.stop()` 
and if you want to start it again then you have to use

`Pace.restart()`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont add PACE CSS on other page where you don't require loader